# if Person is a class(in java) what does Person person; do?

Tags: java, object

`Person` is a class having `Parent` as its subclass.

Consider the following 2 statements:

1. `Person person = new Parent();`
2. `Parent parent= (Parent)person;`

The second statement typecasts `person` object reference variable to `parent`... does this means it modifies (kind of overwrites) the `person` variable or does it create a new copy of `person` reference variable and then typecasts?

For example:

```
double x = 10.5; 
int y = (int)x ;
```

Here the value in `x` is not affected and `y` will be equal to `10`. So does the same thing apply to the `parent` `person` example or is it different?

Comment: In future, please spend more than 10 seconds forming your question. The addition of paragraphs, the correction of grammar and the formatting of your question is the responsibility of ***you*** and not one of us.

Comment: @Matt: eventually you will earn some badge for that, so don't complain

Answer (score 1):

This is different. *double* amd *int* are primitive types, while Person and Parent are classes.

When you cast something to Parent, object is not changed. Cast only forces you to tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing. I'm sure this is object of type Parent".

For you this will result in that both variables (parent and person) will point to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Both `person` and `parent` are references and are different (type). The underlying object is the same though.

Answer (score 1):

No new object are created.

The casting `(Parent)`  just forces the VM to interpret `person` as an instance of `Parent`. If it is not true, it will throw a ClassCastException.

You can do:

```
Person person = new Parent();
```

since Person is a superclass of Parent, every Parent instance is also a Person instance.

But from `person` you cannot use methods that are defined in Parent.

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Person person = parent; // Ok, two instances to the the same object.
parent.setNumberOfSons(2); // Ok
person.setNumberOfSons(2); // Compile error, Person does not have that method (even if the instance is a person).
Parent parent2 = (Parent) person;
parent2.setNumberOfSons(2); // Ok
```

Note that doing this:

```
Person person = new Person();
Parent parent = (Parent) person;
```

Will throw the ClassCastException (the object is not an instance of Parent).

Also, if Person does not extend String, then this

```
String myString = new String();
Person person = (Person) myString;
```

will be a compile error (while a Person can be a Parent, a String cannot be a Person since one does not extend the other).

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you basically do is, that you first create a variable of type Person to which you asign an instance of the more special class Parent. This is similar to doing something like

```
Set<string,object> mySet = new Hashset<>();
```

Here you asign an instance of an implemented class to an Interface variable.

In the second step you create a second variable to which you asign the previously created instance. Since the compiler is oblivious to the fact that you created an instance of the class Parent you have to manually type cast the content of the Person-typed variable to fit the Parent-typed one.

Nothing is actually changed by this, you just promise the compiler that things are going to be alright.

Answer (score 0):

Example (it can help to understand):

```
class ClassA {
    public int i = 10;
}

class ClassB : ClassA {
}

ClassB b = new ClassB();
ClassA a = (ClassA)b;
a.i += 10;
// now b.i = 20
```

When you cast double to int, it create new variable, when you cast one class to other you don't create new variable, you only tell compiler that this variable can be treat like some other class